# Auto page-break in Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns, page-break, page-break-inside

I am working on a print stylesheet for a web application. The application uses bootstrap. Every page should be printable and as much whitespace should be removed as possible.

My problem involves the following HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="line">...</div>
    <div class="line">...</div>
    <div class="line">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="line">...</div>
    <div class="line">...</div>
    <div class="line">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a two column layout and each column features several lines. Is there a way to enable page-break between lines in the columns?

The columns can have a lot of lines and I want to avoid that the whole div is shifted to a new page. Instead I want to have a page-break between the lines of the div.

I think the main problem I am facing is that I have table that is constructed column by column and not row by row like a normal HTML table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right: because this is structured as css columns instead of as a `<table>`, you won't be able to do this without using a script to heavily modify the DOM.

But the solution isn't too tricky. Let's think about what you want: a grid that `@media screen` has three rows and on `@media print` puts each row on its own page. If each row was grouped in a single element, you could use the [`page-break-after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after) and/or [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) CSS properties to put each row on its own page. In your markup each row is

`.row .col-x .line`

which both gets in the way of your print formatting and isn't semantic. Let's make each row a `.row`!

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@media print {
  .rows-print-as-pages .row {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  /* include this style if you want the first row to be on the same page as whatever precedes it */
  /*
  .rows-print-as-pages .row:first-child {
    page-break-before: avoid;
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container rows-print-as-pages">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">first row left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">first row right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">second row left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">second row right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">third row left</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">third row right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Here the breaks don't go in the right place without a `.container`. Depending on the rest of you page, the `.container` may not be necessary.)

Checking `@media print` styles is a little inconvenient, but you can do it by making a demo in [codepen](http://www.codepen.io), selecting the "debug" view, and then looking at the print preview or saving as a pdf. Here's a link to [the codepen debug view of the above snippet](http://s.codepen.io/henry/debug/yaypBg)